# Как создать глобальный массив типа double

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli

Недавно начал программировать на Visual C++. Никак не могу объявить массив глобально. Необходимо, чтобы элементы массива были видны во всех формах.

Comment: Вы уверены насчёт C++? Может быть, вы случайно программируете на C++/CLI?

Comment: Создаю так: File > New > Project > Visual C++ > Windows Form Application

Comment: Окей, подойдём с другой стороны. Вы _знаете_, что такое C++/CLI, и чем отличается от C++?

Comment: Думаю, что нет, но как говорит вики это "C++/CLI — привязка языка программирования С++ к среде программирования .NET фирмы Microsoft". Это мой первый проект, до этого я программировал консольные приложения в Dev-C++, CodeBlocks. Это явно не C++/CLI :)

Comment: Примеры смотрю из книги Пахомов Б.И. C/C++ и MS Visual C++ 2012 для начинающих. - СПб.: БХВ-Петербург, 2013. - 512 с.: ил. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Окей. Вы на самом деле программируете не на C++, а на диалекте, именуемом C++/CLI. В нём, в отличие от настоящего C++, нету глобальных *управляемых* массивов. Но есть статические классы, которые означают почти то же.

Попробуйте так:

```
public ref class GlobalVariables abstract sealed
{
public:
    static array<double>^ globalArray;
};
```

Разумеется, стоит придумать имена получше.

---

Чаще всего вам нужен не массив, а более удобный `List`. (У `List`, в отличие от массива, переменный размер.)

---

Если вы уж пишете на .NET, имеет смысл подумать о переходе на C#. Он гораздо удобнее и проще, чем C++/CLI, а по возможностям во многом даже шире.

Comment: А где это нужно прописать этот волшебный код?

Comment: С переменными я делал так: создал common.h в common.cpp. В первый (common.h) пишу int variable1;. Во втором так extern int variable1;. Далее подключал через include :)

Comment: @fedor-sg: В любом .cpp-файле, по идее. (Не уверен, нужны ли forward-декларации в header'е, попробуйте без них.)

Comment: Элементы инициализируем так globalArray[0] = "testing"; ?

Comment: @fedor-sg: сначала надо написать где-нибудь `GlobalVariables::globalArray = gcnew array<System::String^>(10)` (именно `gcnew`, а не `new`). 10 — это размер. Затем можно обращаться: `GlobalVariables::globalArray[0] = "I did it again :("`.

Comment: @fedor-sg: Вот немного документации: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtbydz1t.aspx

Comment: @fedor-sg: Только заметил, что вам нужен `double`. Для него не нужна внутренняя «крышка». Отредактировал ответ.

Comment: Что не особо хорошо получается. Массив виден, но пределах той формы, где она объявлен. В form1.h начале я написал тот код что выше ваш. Там где TODO: Add the constructor code here написал GlobalVariables::globalArray = gcnew array<System::String^>(10);. В private: System::Void button2_Click_1(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) все успешно правится. А вот в form2 уже не видит этот массив.

Comment: @fedor-sg: Тогда перенесите класс в header. Должно помочь, по идее.

Comment: При попытке написать MessageBox::Show(GlobalVariables::globalArray[0]); выдает "error C2653: 'GlobalVariables' : is not a class or namespace name" и
"error C2653: 'GlobalVariables' : is not a class or namespace name"

Comment: @fedor-sg: Это после переноса в header?

Comment: Нет не переносил пока. В какой header?

Comment: @fedor-sg: Класс `GlobalVariables`. В header, как и обычные классы. (В любой, по идее.)

Comment: Пока не понял вас :). Вот как у меня, когда для пределов в одной форме namespace Monte_Carlo {

public ref class GlobalVariables abstract sealed
{
 public:
  static array<System::String^>^ globalArray;
};

 using namespace System;
 using namespace System::ComponentModel;
 using namespace System::Collections;
 using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
 using namespace System::Data;
 using namespace System::Drawing;

Comment: @fedor-sg: Выложите лучше на pastebin.com, а?

Comment: @fedor-sg: Может, вы забыли `#include`?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/87RGRrZT

Comment: @fedor-sg: Окей. Строка 31 в pastebin — //Form1 это .cpp или .h?

Comment: .h. Забыл добавить сорри.

Comment: @fedor-sg: Попробуйте в Form2.h наверху написать `#include "Form1.h"`. Или в `Form3.х`. Там, где не видит, короче.

Comment: Вы правы насчет C#. Все тоже самое набрал и в нем все работает на ура! Пока C++/CLI :)

Comment: @fedor-sg: Воооооот! Приветствую новообращённого :)