# C++/CLI, глобальный экземпляр формы

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli

Есть вопрос по C++.

В моем проекте есть 3 формы.

- MyForm - с нее начинается запуск приложения.
- Visitors и Coachs открываются из MyForm при нажатии на соответствующую кнопку.

Мне нужно, чтобы, если будут открыты все 3 формы, и я нажимаю кнопку в Coachs, обновлялся richTextBox в Visitors.

Проблема в том, что экземпляр формы Visitors не глобальный, а определен только в ней и MyForm и я не могу обновить информацию таким образом (`vis->richTextBox->Text = "text"`).

Пробовал делать экземпляр глобальным в каком-либо файле, но компилятор в VS2012 ругается "переменная со статической длительностью не может быть дескриптором или относиться к типу отслеживаемой ссылки".

Так же пытался сделать так, как написано в этом блоке (последний коммент).
http://www.sql.ru/forum/741050/dostup-k-gui-windows-forms
Но здесь при вызове Init в аргументе так же нужно передавать экземпляр Visitors, а в Coachs он не определен.
Буду очень признателен за ценный совет и решение проблемы.

Comment: Упал вам этот ужасный C++/CLI. Пишите лучше не православном C#.

Comment: Я бы и сам рад написать на c#, но что сделать с преподом, если он хочет c++.

Comment: Эх. Такое недавно спрашивали, смотрите [сюда](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416878/10105). Только вместо глобального массива у вас будет глобальная форма.

Comment: `ref class GlobalVisitorForm
{
public:
    static Visitors^ form2;
};` Я написал вот так в отдельном файле, файл подключил, выдаются ошибки error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед "^" (это на строке static Visitors^ form2;) И при вызове в форме Coachs  GlobalVisitorForm::form2->VisitorInfo(); (form2 не является членом GlobalVisitorForm)

Comment: Попробуйте forward declaration: `ref class Visitors;` перед классом `GlobalVisitorForm`.

Comment: если я Вас правильно понял, то он сейчас говорит, что Visitors не является однозначным ` ref class Visitors;
ref class GlobalVisitorForm
{
public:
     Visitors^ form2;
};`

Comment: Раз препод хочет С++, так и пишите на С++/Qt. с++cli очень сложная штука, и совсем не для формочек сделана.

Comment: Lol4t0, по-моему довольно глупо переделывать сейчас весь проект, если он почти готов, остался только этот баг.

Comment: Хм. Дайте весь лог компиляции, а? Лучше в вопрос. Или на pastebin.com.

Comment: VladD, вот проект, посмотрите, если не сложно, лог слишком большой, чтобы присылать сюда https://yadi.sk/d/_3hVIqXHgFz4t

Comment: Окей, сейчас гляну

Comment: А, понятно. Вы в `cc.h` декларируете класс `Visitors` в глобальном namespace, а на самом деле он в `namespace ооп`. Делайте так: http://pastebin.com/h4krmajt

Comment: Спасибо огромное, все работает!

Comment: Вот и хорошо. :-) Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для будущих поколений: в рамках данного проекта проблему решает следующий код:

```
namespace ооп
{
    // forward-декларация
    ref class Visitors;

    // объявление статического класса
    ref class GlobalVisitorForm abstract sealed
    {
    public:
        static Visitors^ GlobalForm;
    };
}
```

Дело в том, что для управляемых данных не существует глобальных переменных. Вы должны положить переменную в статический класс. Статических классов как таковых в C++/CLI тоже не существует, но общепринятый способ их эмуляции — использование атрибутов `abstract sealed`.

---

А вообще, конечно, неплохо бы переделать структуру программы так, чтобы каждая форма в конструкторе получала то, что ей нужно. Глобальные переменные — зло.