# C++/CLI Передача данных между формами/ глобальные переменные

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli

В моем проекте 3 формы. Есть переменные (несколько экземпляром классов и векторов), которые должны изменяться во всех файлах, если я меняю что-то в одном месте.

Вопрос в том, как лучше это реализовать?

У меня они были объявлены в отдельном .h файле все как `static` и это работало до поры до времени.

Еще знаю вариант, что можно их объявить отдельно в каждой форме и передавать в конструкторе.

Еще, можно объявить отдельный namespace или статический класс и записать переменные туда.

Так вот, как лучше и, самое главное, правильнее сделать это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ээх.

Значит так. Сначала, по поводу `static`. Модификатор `static` означает «локальный в данной единице компиляции». То есть, в одном `.cpp`-файле и включенных в него header'ах. Поэтому *два* .cpp-файла видят **разные** экземпляры `static`-переменной. Это в принципе не может использоваться для глобальных переменных, никак. Непонятно, почему по вашим словам это «работало».

Глобальные переменные в C и C++, а также глобальные нативные переменные в C++/CLI объявляются так:

В .h-файле декларация того, что переменная есть где-то:

```
extern int x;
```

В .cpp-файле реальное объявление:

```
int x = 5;
```

Глобальные *управляемые* переменные в C++/CLI не существуют, но легко эмулируются статическими полями статического класса, как указано в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/419439/10105).

---

По поводу того, как избавиться от глобальных переменных — длинная история. По идее, вы должны переписать классы так, чтобы они получали нужные данные в конструкторе. Или имели ссылки на другие классы, где можно запросить нужную информацию. Или ещё одним из тысячи возможных способов, вам как архитектору программы самому решать, как именно распределять ответственности между вашими классами. Универсальной рекомендации не существует.

Comment: неплохо бы объяснить минус.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все работает:)